# SL(2) holomorphic discrete series are cohomological

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Consider the holomorphic discrete series on $SL(2,\mathbb R)$. It is also known that they are cohomological representations, i.e, their associated $(\mathfrak g,K)$-module $V$ gives rise to a non-trivial Lie algebra cohomology $H^*(\mathfrak g,K;V)$. I am looking for a proof of this statement.

Comment: Really, any example of holomorphic discrete series will do.

Comment: So the Eisenstein series $f(z) = \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma} (\frac{d}{dz} \gamma . z)^k$ of a discrete subgroup $\Gamma \subset SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, $F(g) = f(g .i), g \in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ ? What is the statement you want to show in that case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference here http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ntanabe/hilbert_arithmetic.pdf on p.10 which explains this exactly.